# How to find a real orthogonal matrix?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, hessian-matrix

> Find a real orthogonal matrix of order 3, other than ±I3, having all integer elements.

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you find a $2\times 2$ orthogonal matrix with integer entries?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Try to swap the columns of the matrix that you are not allowed to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can come up with a lot:
\begin{equation}
\pmb{A} =
\begin{bmatrix}
k_1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & k_2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & k_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $k_i$ are integers. There's a lot you can come up with.

Comment: Are you sure that there're lots of options here? Remember that **not only** it must be $\;\det A=\pm1\;$, but in fact it *must* fulfill $\;AA^t=I\;$ . With your example, this traduces to $$A^2=\begin{pmatrix}
k_1^2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & k_2^2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & k_3^2 \\
\end{pmatrix}=I$$ so there seem to exist pretty few cases here...

Comment: yes it's good you pointed that out .. Forgot to mention that though .. So yes you can choose $k_i = \pm 1$.